# Arduino MKR (RS)485 error with Piezo Motor

Tags: arduino, rs485, motordriver

I have a problem with my new project.
The goal is to **control** my **piezo motor** with an **Arduino MKR Wifi 1010** via **RS485**.
For that reason I have these components:

Arduino MKR Wifi 1010
Arduino MKR 485 Shield
Piezo Motordriver PM401  (Manual: https://piezomotor.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/150025_PMD401_Technical_Manual.pdf)
Piezo LEGS motor

I tested the RS485 by using a USB adapter and the piezomotor software. That worked.
But if it comes to code, I don't get any further.

The commands I want to send the piezodriver in ASCII Code is:
X127M2;
X127J200,0,100;
(They worked in the PiezoMotor DriveLab Software)

And I try to do it with this code:

```
#include <ArduinoRS485.h>

int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  RS485.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  RS485.receive();
}

void loop() {
  RS485.beginTransmission();
 
  if (RS485.available()){
    Serial.println(RS485.read());
  }
  else {
    Serial.write("Not available");
  }
  Serial.println(RS485.available());
  RS485.write('X127M2;');
  RS485.write('X127J200,0,100;');
  Serial.print("Count No: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  RS485.endTransmission();
  counter ++;
  delay(2000);
}
```

In the terminal I got something like that:

```
88
8
Count No: 1
50
15
Count No: 2
67
22
Count No: 3
```

How do I know, that the MKR 485 Shield is sending the commands to the Piezodriver and not to nowhere? And the numbers of the terminal seems to me random. They also appear even if nothing is connected to the MKR 485 Shield.
So how can I find or set the address of the PM401 in the code?
Or do I have to send the commands completly different?
They have to be in ASCII send at 115200n81. Does the line `RS485.write('X127M2;');` provide that?

I'm a bit lost, also cause I don't have a lot experince in that field, and try&error does not work here.
Hope there are some tips out there :)

Comment: please note that this is not a manual reading service. please read [ask]

Comment: stop editing your question, read the manual. time is invested much better. 4 hours later you're still sending the wrong commands. if you expect a response you may not terminate your command with semicolon. it will suppress the controllers response!  please read the manuals. it will save you a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I got it now, it was a stupid cable problem. The **Y** output from the MKR 485 Shield have to go to the Data **+** from the PMD401 and the **Z** to the Data **-**. Not the over way around, like its everywhere discriped.

Here is the final test code for everybody outthere who will try the same:

```
#include <ArduinoRS485.h>

int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  RS485.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  RS485.receive();
}

void loop() {
  RS485.beginTransmission();
 
  if (RS485.available()){
    Serial.println(RS485.read());
  }
  else {
    Serial.write("Not available");
  }
  RS485.write("X127M2;");
  delay(500);
  RS485.write("X127J200,0,200;");
  delay(2000);
  RS485.write("X127J-200,0,200;");
  Serial.print("Count No: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  RS485.endTransmission();
  counter ++;
  delay(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need a adress? And if, how do I get it.

This is explained in the manual... Read it!

> Also is the Piezodriver Half or Full duplex?

The manual only lists one pair of data pins. So it must be half-duplex.

> but the example code said it have to be Full Duplex.

The MKR 485 shield supports both half- and full duplex. Read the manual.

> The commands I want to send the piezodriver in ASCII Code is:
>
> X1M2;
>
> X1J200,0,100;

According to the manual commands are terminated with carriage-return. Why do you put a semikolon at the end of the commands?

`RS485.write(X1J200,0,100;);` and `RS485.write('X1M2;');` will not even compile.

Replace you need to use double quotes. Using none or single quotes won't work.

Your commands should looke something like `RS485.write("X1M2\r");`

Comment: With the address, I meant, if I have to scan (or something like that) with the Arduino. I did that when I used the SDA and SCL pins for a Screen. So I thought, maybe it's quite similar. 

ah ok, so halfduplex :) thx for that

That was only wrong in the code here. Did some changes before and got that mistake. Saw that just a second ago. Sorry about that.

Comment: SDA/SCL is I2C. You only have to scan if you don't know the I2C address of your slave. Here you would send to the broadcast address if you forgot which address you set to the controller.

Comment: I used the `RS485.write('X1M2;');` command, cause they worked with the piezosoftware. 
So I wanted to terminate an error there.

I added that code part as well and don't get any response to it.
`if (RS485.available()){
    Serial.println(RS485.read());
  }
  else {
    Serial.write("Not available");
  } `

So how I know, that the driver gets my commands?

Comment: please don't add more code through comments. is receive mode enabled? please update your question or post a new one. I answered all questions you posted in your question. starting a discussion in comments just creates a mess

Comment: ah sorry, thought the same, but didnt know how to handle it better. First time here. Thanks a lot for you help!